# Dart encodeUriComponent Map.keys()

Tags: dictionary, urlencode, dart

There is an example that I have seen in a number of places for encoding a Map as follows:

```dart
#import('dart:uri');
String encodeMap(Map data) {
    return Strings.join(data.getKeys().map((k) {
        return "${encodeUriComponent(k)}=${encodeUriComponent(data[k])}";
    }), "&");
}
```

I'm running what appears to be the latest Dart editor (version 0.2.9_r 16323)
in the above example, for Dart M2, I believe that `data.getKeys()` has been changed to `data.keys()` which I have altered.

However, I get an error when running it in the Editor:

> Exception: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'call'"

I have 2 questions:

- I'm wondering if this above code should still work in M2 with the change indicated (Map.keys())?
- I'm wondering if this above code does something different to: JSON.stringify(data);

Any other pointers are welcome.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes to do :

- `import` syntax has changed.
- `getKeys()` method became a getter called `keys`.

A working version :

```dart
import 'dart:uri';

String encodeMap(Map data) {
    return Strings.join(data.keys.map((k) {
        return "${encodeUriComponent(k)}=${encodeUriComponent(data[k])}";
    }), "&");
}
```

The `String` generated by this `encodeMap` is quite different from the one generated by `JSON.stringify` as you can see in the bellow snippet :

```dart
main() {
  final map = {"a":"b", "c":"d"};
  assert(encodeMap(map) == "a=b&c=d");
  assert(JSON.stringify(map) == '{"a":"b","c":"d"}');
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It answered both of my questions. I missed what to me was the subtlety of getKeys().map() changing to keys.map() rather than keys().map(). The syntax of the solution in encodeMap() is rather cryptic to me at least. Wouldn't it make sense to have a function similar to JSON.stringify() to handle this? Much appreciated, because I spent a long time attempting to solve what to me was a problem. As much as I think Dart is absolutely great, jquery appears to handle this more elegantly with eg. $.ajax(). I presume that Dart doesn't (yet) have something similar.